# Size of a variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Out of interest, is it possible to determine the size of a JavaScript variable, in bytes?

I have a web-app that runs great on the desktop but `blows up`* on the iPad. I'm guessing it's because there's a much more limited amount of memory in iPad Safari, but I'd like to get some idea of what's going on in my app.

I can estimate relative sizes, based on the size of the JSON source, but it'll be even better to know the actual size of the serialised object

- "Blows up" = Safari slows down, then the screen goes black, and I'm back to the standard iPad home screen. Whatever that's called. Looks to me, that Safari has run out of the memory allocated for a browser instance.

Comment: please define... "Blows Up".  It's like getting user error reports that say, "There was an error..."

Comment: @jondavidjohn: or an Error Light...

Comment: It really blows up? Wow! You should definitely file a bug report. Or.. describe your errors better. Much better.

Comment: @Tomalak - Or get medical attention?

Comment: @Toby From the top of my head, number values are 64-bit, strings are 16 bits per character.

Comment: Amusingly and unfortunately the JS specification only says that numbers should "correspond" to 64-bit binary values and be operable via floating point arithmatic (though, bizarrely, ECMA-262 does specify explicitly that strings must be composed of 16 bit integers). I remember reading quite a while ago that either Webkit or Spidermonkey juggled number types internally, I think to keep comparisons faster. That meant that the `i` in `for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)` is likely smaller than in `var i = Math.cos(0)'`. I'm going to update my answer below with a stupid trick that exposes this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This won't directly answer your question. The JS language reference doesn't specify how to store data, so it's up to the groups doing the implementation, in this case the WebKit team, and I've not seen anything public on that. I've definitely not seen anything about Mobile Safari's implementation of WebKit.

What I would say is that things may actually not be running great on the desktop, it's just that the the desktop's speed and size masks "problems" that show up on the mobile devices. On iOS, a browser instance has a ceiling of 10MB in which to operate if I remember correctly, though in practice, you start to hit the wall right around 6 or 7MB. On a PC, when you run out of RAM, the computer will simply just dump out unused memory to the disk. On iOS either resources stop loading (such as images) or the browser just exits (which is probably what you are experiencing).

If you have a Mac, you can snoop on Safari to see how it's doing by using a tool called "Instruments" (it's part of the iOS SDK). If you don't have a Mac or don't want to download the SDK, just open a clean instance of Safari, open up Windows' Task Manager or Mac's Activity Monitor and watch how your memory usage changes when you load up your webapp.

Staying within the 6MB window is annoying. The biggest thing is try to avoid creating new images. For example, this pattern is a huge problem on an iPhone:

```
function placeImage(imagename,targetelement) { 
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = imagename;
    targetelement.appendChild(image);
}
```

In this case, even if you remove the image from the DOM, and even though `image` is scoped within `placeImage`, it will never, ever get released and it is just a matter of time before this application crashes the browser. If this is your case, instead think about how many images you need to display at once, create image objects only for those elements and recycle them (just reset the `src` any time you want a new image).

Also, I've found that JavaScript's application stack is much smaller than on a desktop browser, so if you have a lot of recursion, you'll see the problem much faster on iOS. The way to spot this problem is to open up the Developer Tools in Safari and use the profiler to see what functions are getting called the most.

[edit] I can't remember if this is the exact technique that exposes how numbers are stored differently internally by webkit, but I think it is. Basically, you do a sort on a million random numbers, first with a float, then (if you uncomment the line) an integer and then a large integer. I'm not good with typed languages, so I'm not exactly sure what this proves other than that internally numbers are treated differently depending on their smallest possibly representation.

```
arrTarget = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    arrTarget.push(Math.random() * 16000000);
//  arrTarget.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 16000000));
//  arrTarget.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1600000000000));
}

// Time how long it takes to sort the array:
var time = new Date().getTime();
arrTarget.sort();
console.log(new Date().getTime() - time);
```

Comment: that's a great, useful answer. Thank you Andrew. We've already tried the Instruments app, but Safari didn't show up. I'd guessed that the desktop wasn't showing up the problem, but hadn't thought of looking at Task manager.  6mb does sound about right for the amount of data I've got churning about.  I'm slicing away at it, but it's really useful to know that there's that limit.    I'd looked at the Profiler before, and there's a lot of action in there. I'll have another look in the morning. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something you can do in general, but the sizes of some JavaScript objects are *not* implementation specific, so you do have *some* guarantees:

- "A string value is a member of the type String and is a finite ordered sequence of zero or more 16-bit unsigned integer values."
- "The type Number is a set of values representing numbers. In ECMAScript, the set of values represents the double-precision 64-bit format IEEE 754 values including the special "Not-a-Number" (NaN) values, positive infinity, and negative infinity."

[Source](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-4.3.16)